# How to make Bibtex to ignore year in references?

Tags: bibtex

I need to cite the Bible with no year, so I am using the following in Sources.bib:

```
@article{Bible,
title={New International Version{\textregistered}, NIV{\textregistered} Copyright{\copyright} 1973, 1978, 1984, 2011 by Biblica},
author={Bible, Holy},
year={},
url={www.biblegateway.com}
}
```

In references, it is displayed as:

```
Bible, Holy (????), "New international version ...
```

How to get rid of (????)?

The latex code would be something like below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\cite{Bible} in the text

\newpage

\bibliographystyle{te}
\bibliography{Sources}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe some other entry type would be better suited, maybe `@misc`?

Comment: Can you post a link to `te.bst`.

Comment: That really looks wrong. Are you sure you're meant to have (R) and (C) in the bibliography?

Comment: Not sure actually! I copied it from GoogleScholars. Any ideas how to cite the Bible including the version?

Comment: I agree with @cfr. I would just remove the (R) and (C) from the reference altogether and leave only the year of the version you're actually quoting from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a new `.bib` entry type for this entry, and then modify your `.bst` file to use it.

Make a new copy of `te.bst` and call is `te-bible.bst`.  Add the following function (modelled after the `misc` function).

```
FUNCTION {bible}
{ output.bibitem
  format.btitle output
  new.sentence
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.url output
  new.sentence
  format.note output
  fin.entry
}
```

Now add your bible as entry type `@bible`.

I've created a citation command `\biblecite` to introduce the citation in parentheses.

```
@bible{Bible,
    Title = {The Holy Bible},
    Howpublished = {{New International Version{\textregistered}, NIV{\textregistered} Copyright{\copyright} 1973, 1978, 1984, 2011 by Biblica}}
    }
```

Here's a full working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@bible{Bible,
        Title = {The Holy Bible},
        Howpublished = {{New International Version{\textregistered}, NIV{\textregistered} Copyright{\copyright} 1973, 1978, 1984, 2011 by Biblica}}
        }
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\biblecite}{\citetext{\emph{The Bible}\citeyear{Bible}}}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}


\begin{document}

\biblecite{}

\bibliographystyle{te-bible}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it seems that this gives me a separate "References" section. I need the Bible to be listed within the existing references section.

Comment: @D_B  I don't understand. There's only one references section because there's only one `\bibliography` command. So the bible reference will appear first in the list (since it has no author or year) but otherwise will appear in the same list as all your other references. Maybe you're confused by the `\jobname` stuff. That's just to make the example self contained. You would add the `@bible` entry to your regular `.bib` file.